# compare time delay from mysql database and php input

Tags: php, html, mysql

In my mysql table record, row delay char(8) contains time delay to solve a problem. such as 0:03:45, 0:15:12 etc. now I want to show all the record which exceeds a certain limit say 3s. i want to input this limit through web browser. 
but it is not able to compare the delay

```
<?php
$category=$_POST["category"];
&criteria=$_POST["criteria"];
if ( $category=="delay")
  {

   sql= "SELECT * FROM RECORD WHERE (10*(int)$category[2]+(int)$category[3])>=$criteria";
   }
 ?>
```

also is it possible to write php program so that if 3 is entered it will take as 3 in second???

Comment: `&criteria=$_POST("criteria");` It would be `&criteria=$_POST["criteria"];`

Comment: yes you are right. but this is not the actual problem

Comment: What is your problem???

Comment: when executing sql it shows error